# Unity game slow loading

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am creating a Unity Game and the game works, but it takes ages to load! When I start the game on my iPhone it takes 10-15 minutes to load. I dont have any textures now, I will add those later. The player control is a first person CharacterControler, with a default script from the Unity website.
And a Blender world model (room).
What can I do to make my game load faster?

Comment: Without seeing any code we have no way of knowing what the problem is.

Comment: Uhm the only code I have is for the player control

Comment: What exactly do you have in the scene? What's the "player control" — default CharacterController script? What gameObjects do you have, what materials do they use, what textures do they use? Right now it's a very broad question; optimizing a game is a hard work and is done on individual basis. You won't be able to get more than general advice until you ask something more specific.

Comment: Undeleting at OP's request to provide an opportunity to edit/improve. Please do not delete for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help 
[Unity Iphone Optimisation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/iphone-performance.html)

Comment: So you have measured the performance etc?  Do you have a bunch of assets in the project that you dont need anymore?
also is the game actually on your phone or are you using the unity app to play via your phone?
have you tried it on an alternative device? or an emulator?

Comment: I have Unity Basic so I cant use the profieler... I did build and run and run it on my phone (trough xcode compiler). And I removed all the assets that I dont need anymore. The app is 10 mb so very small!

Comment: I revised my project and the link in your answer did the trick, but I needed Unity Pro. It's working like a charm now, thank you!